# $.when.apply to return result sets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apply

I was wondering if it is possible to return the result of a $.when.apply($, Requests[]) call upon completion of all requests in the ajax call array?

I have used:

```
$.when($.ajax(...)).done(function(data){ console.log(data.d); }
```

Which lets me work with the result of the ajax call. How do I apply the same concept to $.when.apply($, Requests[])? I have tried `$.when.apply($, Requests[]).then(function(data?){ console.log(data.d); }` but that does not work. Any ideas?

Basically, I am trying to run a variable number of similar ajax calls and work with their results once all of them complete. I would appreciate any hints in the right direction!

Edit: Clarification
I setup Requests[] as an array holding ajax request. Example:

```
var Requests = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){ Requests.push($.ajax({...ajax setup...}));
$.when.apply($, Requests).then(function(...){ do Stuff with the result of all });
```

Comment: @KevinB it looks like an array of jqxhr objects

Comment: @KevinB i think the update makes it clear

Comment: I added the [] inside the function to clarify it is an array. I edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: then `then` callback receives a variable number of arguments depending on the number of promises passed to `when` function

Comment: this works when I know the number of requests passed, could you give me a code example, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The then callback receives a variable number of arguments based on the number of promises passed to it.

In this case since ajax promises are passed each of the argument is an array having 3 items data, status and jqxhr object.

So you need to use the bellow syntax to get the result of the first request.

```
then(function(result1){
    console.log(result[0].d)
})
```

to print results of all requests

```
then(function (result1) {
    $.each(arguments, function (idx, args) {
        console.log(args[0]);// in your case args[0].d
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mKK42/)

Comment: Perfect, this is a very clean and working solution! Much appreciated!